# MySQL INSERT ... SELECT multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I've been searching the MySQL documentation, Google and Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the solution which suits my needs.

I have 2 tables:
Contract: contract_id, contract_client_id, contract_property_id, contract_tenant_id, contract_startdate, contract_enddate, contract_price

Ledger: ledger_id, ledger_trans_date, ledger_period, ledger_property_id, ledger_tenant_id, ledger_value

I want to populate the ledger with some columns from the contract table and used the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO ledger (ledger_trans_date, ledger_period, ledger_property_id, 
ledger_tenant_id, ledger_value)
VALUES ('01-08-2018', '01-08-2018', (SELECT contract_property_id, 
contract_tenant_id, contract_price FROM contract));
```

But I get the following error: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

I tried this one as well:

```
INSERT INTO ledger (ledger_trans_date, ledger_period, ledger_property_id, 
ledger_tenant_id, ledger_value)
VALUES ('01-08-2018', '01-08-2018', 
(SELECT contract_property_id FROM contract),
(SELECT contract_tenant_id FROM contract),
(SELECT contract_price FROM contract));
```

But than I get the following error: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

I hope someone can help me ahead and tell me where I went wrong...
In case you need more info, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO ledger (ledger_trans_date, ledger_period, ledger_property_id, 
ledger_tenant_id, ledger_value)
SELECT '2018-08-01', '2018-08-01', contract_property_id, 
contract_tenant_id, contract_price FROM contract;
```

Comment: This gives a syntax error: Error Code 1064.
If I understood the documentation correct this is due to the fact of VALUES (SELECT '01-08-2018', '01-08-2018' ... as the dates are a string... Correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: Wrong date format, it should be 'YYYY-MM-DD' . Rest is fine.

Comment: That doesn't solve the syntax error. I did it according to the code above you sent and change it to 2018-08-01.

Comment: Then please check if `ledger_trans_date` and `ledger_period` are in date/datetime format or not?

Comment: @Dennis Did you checked?

Comment: No, sorry, that's something I didn't mentioned. The date fields are sometimes populated by MySQL. From this perspective it could be a date datatype.
However, it is also populated with user data from a web page then PHP is handling the query. The PHP part works. The reason it is VARCHAR is because I read that having the date-type often leads to difficulties with PHP...
I changed the data-type to DATE, but it is still giving the syntax error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177831/discussion-between-sookie-singh-and-dennis).

Comment: This query puts the same hardcoded values for ledger_trans_date and ledger_period for all inserted records that is, probably, not always correct.